# Can kindle fire highlight text while reading it

Tags: kindle, kindle-app, kindle-fire

I Use Kindle fire HD 7th generation.

I love and use Text to speech capability.

Questions:

Can kindle fire(Text to speech) highlight the text while reading it?

Can any other app reads Kindle books(without changing their format)?